# How to replace int values with objects(PIL-Images) in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I want to plot 4 different images in a grid-style look, distributed randomly over 144 tiles (9x16). To Do so, I created a random matrix with 144 values (every value can take the number 0-3). Then I transferred the values to a data frame and replaced the values with the 4 different images. After that i plot the images via subplots and imshow.

```
matrix = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(16, 9))
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix).astype('object')

filenames = [['test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg'],
             ['test3.jpg', 'test4.jpg']]
images = [[Image.open(fn) for fn in row] for row in filenames]
dfIm = pd.DataFrame(images)

df = df.replace([0],dfIm.iloc[0,0])
df = df.replace([1],dfIm.iloc[0,1])
df = df.replace([2],dfIm.iloc[1,1])
df = df.replace([3],dfIm.iloc[1,0])
```

But the replacement to the numbers in the data frame with the PIL images raises an AssertionError. Does anyone know, how to solve my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just pass the filename as strings into your new dataframe, then when you go to plot add a line to open each file as a PIL object?

Comment: I did not thought about that. It works well, thank you.